# d3js mask to show dots over bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, design-patterns, mask

i saw this example here: https://jsfiddle.net/gruc1vod/4/

and i want to add these dots over my bar chart using mask.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var dotsPatternDefs = svg.append('defs');
    
dotsPatternDefs.append('pattern')
        .attr('id', 'dotsPattern')
        .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
        .attr('width', 10)
        .attr('height', 10)
      .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', 5)
        .attr('cy', 5)
        .attr('r', 3)
        .style('fill', 'white');
    
dotsPatternDefs.append('mask')
        .attr('id', 'mask-dots')
      .append('rect')
        .attr('width', '100%')
        .attr('height', '100%')
        .attr('x', 0)
        .attr('y', 0)
        .style('fill', 'url(#dotsPattern)');
    
svg.append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'dotsPattern')
      .attr('width', '200')
      .attr('height', '200')
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('y', 0)
        .style('fill', '#F189b2');
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
rect.dotsPattern {
    mask: url(#mask-dots);
}
```

and here my live example: https://jsfiddle.net/uao5yfhm/6/

Where is the problem and i cannot see this outcome [correct outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aizaC.png) but i see this one [wrong outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U7rP.png)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**:
just change the circle color into `black` and add one more white rectangle in mask.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

var dotsPatternDefs = svg.append('defs');
    
dotsPatternDefs.append('pattern')
        .attr('id', 'dotsPattern')
        .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
        .attr('width', 10)
        .attr('height', 10)
      .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', 5)
        .attr('cy', 5)
        .attr('r', 3)
        .style('fill', 'black');
 
let mask = dotsPatternDefs.append('mask').attr('id', 'mask-dots')
mask.append('rect')
      .attr('width', '100%')
      .attr('height', '100%')
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('y', 0)
        .style('fill', 'white'); 
mask.append('rect')
      .attr('width', '100%')
      .attr('height', '100%')
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('y', 0)
        .style('fill', 'url(#dotsPattern)'); 

    
svg.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'dotsPattern')
    .attr('width', '200')
    .attr('height', '200')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 0)
    .style('fill', '#F189b2');
```

```css
rect.dotsPattern {
    mask: url(#mask-dots);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.12.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/gspn7a3o/35/

I think you have misunderstood the usage of `mask`. If you fill the pattern circle into white, it means that "Everything under a white pixel will be visible"(See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask)). So the pink rectangle will be seen through these white circles.

So if you are trying to not see through circles, put them in black("Everything under a black pixel will be invisible") and also give a white rectangle mask to make sure the pink can be seen.

My first answer here, ask me if you have any more questions.